# mvc : control specific required validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, html-helper

I am using mvc 2.0 with C#.Net
In my view page, I am creating multiple controls with required field validations. to plot my controls, I am using for loop through my mode object which is actually a collection of business object. For my TextBox control which represent 'user comments', I have put validation under it. like

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.mycollection[i].Comment %>
<%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mycollection[i].comments) %>
```

There is a sumit button for each row (for each comment textbox) like below

```
<input runat="Server" name="Button" id="Submit1" type="submit" class="button" value="save comments">
```

When the form loads, 3 rows are created, each containing a set of text box and a button to submit. This is because the model is a collection of 3 objects. So now I can submit each comments entered by user individually. But the problem is, when I click on any button, instead of validating corresponding textbox for required validation, it validates all of the textboxes on page at a time and gives error message for all of them. How to avoid this kind of behaviour? Mypage has a html.beginform method on top to put everything in a single form and to post the submit to an controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put each object from your collection in a separate form like this:

```
<table>
     <% foreach(person in Model.Personlist)  { %>       
   <tr>       
 <td>
  <form>
   <%=Html.TextAreaFor(...) %> 
   <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)  %>
   <input type="button"......></input>
  </form>
  </td>   
  </tr>  
   <% } %> 
 </table>
```

..so then only that form will be validated when you click submit.
Also you can use divs instead of table .

Comment: Thanks! I will try div option. As there will be large amount of controls, it will lead to number of forms on single page..

Comment: Is there any other whay to do it? other than form tag?

Comment: I have chaned qording in my question to make it more clear to all.